# Typescript: How to specify the result of a function which has several generics?

Tags: typescript

How to specify the result of a function which has several generics? This is my not working code:

```
const getter = <T, K>(age: T, name: K):T,K => `${age} and ${name}`;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions can only return a single value, so it's unclear what you really want here.

That said, are you looking for a [string template literal](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) solution?

For example you can type the return type as `${T} and ${K}` to return a specific string type.

```
const getter =
  <
    T extends number,
    K extends string
  >(
    age: T,
    name: K
  ): `${T} and ${K}` => `${age} and ${name}`;

  const test = getter(50, "Gertrude") // test is of type "50 and Gertrude"

  const typeError: "25 and Mary" = getter(50, "Gertrude") // error
  // Type '"50 and Gertrude"' is not assignable to type '"25 and Mary"'.(2322)
```

Note the `T extends number` and `K extends string`. That's how you require that generics be of a certain type going into your function.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&ts=4.3.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUylBAnGBeAUDGAeHXGAFRgQA8UwATCGMAVwFsAjNAGkNwGkzKEadaKgCWYOIQB8ACi4wAhogBcJTkXrymCFd0IBKFQAMAJAG9iAXwU0YZ7hcOZJME6cUIr8m2bCaPhgG4sLFBIWBRoTHgkFFRpAFYABnYYACIAcTQoVAZqBFS9EPBIqABPAAcEAFFUVBBUFVSAJnjrahgAWXlUUtSoxGQ0BOS0zNRs3Py9IA)

---

Or you could return a tuple:

```
[T, K]
```

Or an object:

```
{ [name in K]: T }
```

So figure out how the generic types fit into your return type, and then put them in the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your function just returns a string..?

```
const getter = <T, K>(age: T, name: K):string => `${age} and ${name}`;
```

[Working TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUylBAnGBeGAeAKgGhgGkA+ACgENEAuGAmMCgWwVqIEprpUBLMOTCRgADACQBvKggC+MCmAAmMCYxbThAbgCwAKCA)

Comment: It should return a number and a string

Comment: your function returns `\`${age} and ${name}\``...that is not a number and a string, that is a string.  also a function cannot return "a number and a string".... a function can only return a singular value.

Comment: const getter = <T, K>(age: T, name: K) => `${age} and ${name}`;
getter(10, "Anny");

No problem at all. T must be one type of data, K is another.

Comment: There won't be a problem with that because you're not specifying the return value.  Typescript is inferring it to be a string, because that's what you're returning. `\`${age} and ${name}\`` is a string.  You're not returning two different data types.  You're returning a string. Alex Wayne's answer is pretty great if you want to force a very specific kind of string, but it is ultimately only a string.